# Regex expression to capitalise first character

Tags: javascript, regex

For the address field, I need first character of every word to be uppercase. I have been using `/\b./g` which has eventually resulted in a problem where first character after special characters such as `!@*&;'` and so on are also capitalised. ie. `King'S Street` instead of `King's Street`.

Is there a way to adjust that expression to exclude that behaviour or is changing the entire expression more optimal?

Comment: JavaScript, right?

Comment: There are some great online tools with instructions for testing your regex e.g. https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `\b` with `(^|[ ])`

Your regex will be: `/(^|[ ])./g`

**Explanation:**

`\b` by [definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_begin.asp): is used to find a match at the beginning or end of a word.

`(^|[ ])` will match with the beginning of the string or any space characters

`(^|[ ]).` will match every space followed by a character and the first character of the string.

**Side note:**

Use `(^|\s)` to match every blank spaces.

Your regex will be: `/(^|\s)./g`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead:

```
\b[a-z](?=\w+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nF2pT3/1).

Comment: won't work with `a` and `i`. check this: `"i am a student"`

Comment: won't work with `őúéá` or any other unicode characters.